# Fetch row data from known index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

```
   col1   col2
0   a     5
1   b     2
2   c     1
```

df2:

```
   col1
0   qa0
1   qa1
2   qa2
3   qa3
4   qa4
5   qa5
```

final output:

```
   col1   col2  col3
0   a     5     qa5
1   b     2     qa2
2   c     1     qa1
```

Basically , in df1, I have index stored for another df data. I have to fetch data from df2 and append it in df1. 
I don't know how to fetch data via index number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by another `Series`:

```
df1['col3'] = df1['col2'].map(df2['col1'])
```

Or use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `rename` column:

```
df1 = df1.join(df2.rename(columns={'col1':'col3'})['col3'], on='col2')
```

---

```
print (df1)
  col1  col2 col3
0    a     5  qa5
1    b     2  qa2
2    c     1  qa1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iloc` to get data and then `to_numpy` for values

```py
df1["col3"] = df2.iloc[df1.col2].to_numpy()

df1
  col1  col2 col3
0    a     5  qa5
1    b     2  qa2
2    c     1  qa1
```